# Is there a way to disable FCM topic subscriptions from client, to use only serverside topic subscriptions?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

For security reasons we are thinking about managing topic subscriptions only on serverside. Is there a way to disable topic management on client devices?

Comment: you should move the topic subscription part to server-side or at least validate the request on your first and then validate and then call the API to subscribe

Comment: yes, but on client side with sdk will still be possible to subscribe, the client needs the sdk to receive notifications

Comment: Maybe make the client API key a "restricted key", and enable only APIs you need (exclude `Firebase Cloud Messaging API` and/or `Cloud Messaging API`). I haven't tried this, not sure which one does the trick. Find the API keys here https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials.